# ASP.Net Core 3.0 app URL was not found with Path parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

we have defined `AddMvc()` and `UseMvc()` methods in our startup.cs file bur, however, the controller action is not found by hitting the URL directly as below

```
https://localhost:44384/api/weatherforecast/getmyWeather/10
```

isn't working in our browser, however, `https://localhost:44384/api/weatherforecast/getmyWeather` & `https://localhost:44384/api/weatherforecast/getmyWeather?id=10` works

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            //app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            //{
            //    endpoints.MapControllers();
            //});
            app.UseMvc(routes => { routes.MapRoute("default", "api/{controller=Default}/{action=Index}/{id?}"); });
        }
    }
```

And on **WeatherForecastController.cs**

```
[ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]

    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
            "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
        };

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("getmyWeather")]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> getmyWeather(int id)
        {
            var rng = new Random(id);
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Not sure why Path parameters in URL are not working but querystrings does. what am I missing here?

Comment: Partial Answer is correct Rahul, a little digging showed that simple types are mapped by query and complex types by req body..so, I have to set the route mapping `Route(getmyWeather/{id})` on the method level and it started working for me.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use conventional routes for `API`, you need to disable attribute route on `API`. In your startup.cs:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
          endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "Default",
            pattern: "{controller=default}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

And your `Controller` will look like:

```
    //[ApiController]
    //[Route("api/[controller]")]    
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
            "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"};

    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("getmyWeather")]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> getmyWeather(int id)
    {
        var rng = new Random(id);
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();
    }
}
```

OR you can create your own custom base controller and use that:

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]/{id?}")]
[ApiController]
public class MyBaseController : ControllerBase
{
}
```

And your `Controller`:

```
public class WeatherForecastController : MyBaseController 
{
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
            "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"};

    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("getmyWeather")]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> getmyWeather(int id)
    {
        var rng = new Random(id);
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();
    }
}
```